# How can I display my attributes in view.js? [@wordpress/create-block]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm new to wordpress and i tried the command to generate a wordpress/block

`npx @wordpress/create-block wis-slider --no-plugin`

In this folder i get a "view.js" were i can load external libraries like swiper.js

Unfortunately, i do not know how to display the block attributes in view.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple way to get attributes in view.js is to pass as varibales in save.js like this using JSON.stringnify() (code line: { `var testimonialsSlides=${ JSON.stringify(slides) }` } ):

```
export default function Save({ attributes }) {
const { title, slides } = attributes;

const {blockClassName, blockStyleObject } = useBlockStyle( 'testimonials', {
    color: attributes.color,
    bgColor: attributes.bgColor,
} );

const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({
    className: `${blockClassName} ${blockClassName}-${ attributes.clientId }`,
    style: blockStyleObject
});

return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
        <div className={`${blockClassName}__icon`}></div>
        <RichText.Content value={ title  } tagName="p" className={`${blockClassName}__title`} />

        <div className={`swiper ${blockClassName}__swiper`}>
            <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                {slides.map(( slide, index  ) => (
                    <div className={ `swiper-slide ${ index === 0 ? 'swiper-slide-active' : '' }` }>
                        <div  className="wp-block-oimocode-testimonials__item">
                            <div className="wp-block-oimocode-testimonials__rating">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
                            </div>
                            <RichText.Content value={ slide.content } tagName="p" className={`${blockClassName}__review`} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="swiper-pagination">
                {slides.map(( slide, index  ) => (
                    <span className={ `swiper-pagination-bullet ${ index === 0 ? 'swiper-pagination-bullet-active' : '' }` }>
                        { slide.imgUrl && <img src={ slide.imgUrl } alt={ `reviewer-avatar-${ index }` } />}
                        { ! slide.imgUrl && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} /> }
                    </span>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>{ `var testimonialsSlides=${ JSON.stringify(slides) }` }</script>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**